# openai_ros example in local computer does not work

Tags: roslaunch, turtlebot, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I'm trying to this [openai_ros gym tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/openai_ros/TurtleBot2%20with%20openai_ros), **not using ROS Development Studio(RDS)**.

I already checked that it does work in RDS following step by step. There was not problem at all.

**BUT**, I couldn't do this same tutorial in my local computer. It was troubled on the just first step.

If I type the following on my local command terminal,

```
  roslaunch gym_construct main.launch
```

then it shows that

```
 [ INFO] [1537961641.295151763, 0.348000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): Advertise joint_states
 [ INFO] [1537961641.295818023, 0.348000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): Try to subscribe to cmd_vel
 [ INFO] [1537961641.298928159, 0.348000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): Subscribe to cmd_vel
 [ INFO] [1537961641.299555014, 0.348000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): Advertise odom on odom 
 [spawn_turtlebot_model-2] process has finished cleanly
 log file: /home/parkbj/.ros/log/043fb95e-c180-11e8-8ab1-7085c22a655c/spawn_turtlebot_model-2*.log
```

And then, there is nothing happened. **Gazebo** has to be loaded, but **NOT**.

This problem is not only for local computer. It does though for RDS.

If I just type the same command in the **Shell of RDS, instead of Simulations tap > Select a launch file > main.launch**,
then I get a exactly same result.

I want to try this tutorial in local computer to integrate a reinforcement learning part included in it with my own robot later.

However, **how to do this tutorial in the local computer, not using RDS is nowhere.**
Please let me know this.

**FIY**, the following is the **all step of my trials** on command terminal **in local computer** for doing this tutorial.

1. Download [Turtlebot2Maze](https://bitbucket.org/theconstructcore/turtlebot/src) pkgs, and set branch.

   ```
   cd ~/catkin_ws/src
   git clone https://bitbucket.org/theconstructcore/turtlebot.git
   cd ~/catkin_ws/src/turtle
   git fetch && git checkout kinetic
   cd ~/catkin_ws
   catkin_make
   source devel/setup.bash
   ```
2. Download [openai_ros](https://bitbucket.org/theconstructcore/openai_ros/src/kinetic-devel/) pkgs, and set branch.

   ```
   cd ~/catkin_ws/src
   git clone https://bitbucket.org/theconstructcore/openai_ros.git
   cd ~/catkin_ws/src/openai_ros
   git fetch && git checkout kinetic-devel
   cd ~/catkin_ws
   catkin_make
   source devel/setup.bash
   ```
3. Download [openai_examples_projects](https://bitbucket.org/theconstructcore/openai_examples_projects/src) pkgs, and set branch.

   ```
   cd ~/catkin_ws/src
   git clone https://bitbucket.org/theconstructcore/openai_examples_projects.git
   cd ~/catkin_ws/src/openai_examples_projects
   git fetch && git checkout tutorials
   cd ~/catkin_ws
   catkin_make
   source devel/setup.bash
   ```
4. Download [open_ai_gym_construct](https://bitbucket.org/theconstructcore/open_ai_gym_construct/src) pkgs, and set branch.

   ```
   cd ~/catkin_ws/src
   git clone https://bitbucket.org/theconstructcore/open_ai_gym_construct.git
   cd ~/catkin_ws/src/open_ai_gym_construct
   git fetch && git checkout master
   cd ~/catkin_ws
   catkin_make
   source devel/setup.bash
   ```
5. Launch **gym_construct main.launch** file in command terminal.

   ```
   roslaunch gym_construct main.launch
   ```
6. Then, the command terminal shows this result. (This is exactly same with the result of shell in RDS)

   ```
   parkbj@parkbj-desktop:~$ roslaunch gym_construct main.launch
   ... logging to /home/parkbj/.ros/log/043fb95e-c180-11e8-8ab1-7085c22a655c/roslaunch-parkbj-desktop-4063.log
   Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
   Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
   Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

   xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
   To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
   For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
   deprecated: xacro tags should be prepended with 'xacro' xml namespace.
   Use the following script to fix incorrect usage:
           find . -iname "*.xacro" | xargs sed -i 's#<\([/]\?\)\(if\|unless\|include\|arg\|property\|macro\|insert_block\)#<\1xacro:\2#g'
   when processing file: /home/parkbj/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot/turtlebot_description/robots/kobuki_hexagons_asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro

   xacro.py is deprecated; please use xacro instead
   started roslaunch server http://161.122.112.91:35127/

   SUMMARY
   ========

   PARAMETERS
   * /cmd_vel_mux/yaml_cfg_file: /home/parkbj/catk...
   * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
   * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency: 30.0
   * /rosdistro: kinetic
   * /rosversion: 1.12.14
   * /use_sim_time: True

   NODES
      /
         cmd_vel_mux (nodelet/nodelet)
         gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
         mobile_base_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
         robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
         spawn_turtlebot_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

   ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

   process[gazebo-1]: started with pid [4101]
   process[spawn_turtlebot_model-2]: started with pid [4106]
   process[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-3]: started with pid [4107]
   process[cmd_vel_mux-4]: started with pid [4108]
   process[robot_state_publisher-5]: started with pid [4109]
   [ INFO] [1537961639.689863296]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
   [ INFO] [1537961639.690056913]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
   [ INFO] [1537961640.512301039, 0.022000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
   [ INFO] [1537961640.548841526, 0.057000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
   [ INFO] [1537961641.115425855, 0.348000000]: Camera Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/'
   [ INFO] [1537961641.118853132, 0.348000000]: Camera Plugin (ns = /)  <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
   [ INFO] [1537961641.192125663, 0.348000000]: Laser Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/'
   [ INFO] [1537961641.192238237, 0.348000000]: Starting GazeboRosLaser Plugin (ns = /)
   [ INFO] [1537961641.193612622, 0.348000000]: GPU Laser Plugin (ns = /) <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
   [ INFO] [1537961641.194959259, 0.348000000]: LoadThread function completed
   [ INFO] [1537961641.291780997, 0.348000000]: Starting plugin DiffDrive(ns = //)
   [ WARN] [1537961641.291884756, 0.348000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): missing <rosDebugLevel> default is na
   [ INFO] [1537961641.293028751, 0.348000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): <tf_prefix> = 
   [ WARN] [1537961641.293188294, 0.348000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): missing <publishWheelTF> default is false
   [ WARN] [1537961641.293204831, 0.348000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): missing <publishOdomTF> default is ture
   [ WARN] [1537961641.293446885, 0.348000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): missing <wheelAcceleration> default is 0
   [ WARN] [1537961641.293479654, 0.348000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): missing <wheelTorque> default is 5
   [ WARN] [1537961641.293972331, 0.348000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): missing <odometrySource> default is 1
   [ WARN] [1537961641.294292592, 0.348000000]: GazeboRosDiffDrive Plugin (ns = ) missing <publishTf>, defaults to 1
   [ INFO] [1537961641.295151763, 0.348000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): Advertise joint_states
   [ INFO] [1537961641.295818023, 0.348000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): Try to subscribe to cmd_vel
   [ INFO] [1537961641.298928159, 0.348000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): Subscribe to cmd_vel
   [ INFO] [1537961641.299555014, 0.348000000]: DiffDrive(ns = //): Advertise odom on odom 
   [spawn_turtlebot_model-2] process has finished cleanly
   log file: /home/parkbj/.ros/log/043fb95e-c180-11e8-8ab1-7085c22a655c/spawn_turtlebot_model-2*.log
   ```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304330/openai_ros-example-in-local-computer-does-not-work./) by [danny p](https://answers.ros.org/users/37750/danny-p/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-09-26

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) on 2018-10-16**:
Remember that if you want to execute the demos locally you have to have the simulations installed in your computer (ROSDS has them installed by default).

**Comment by [steven1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/39530/steven1234/) on 2019-01-18**:
Hi, @danny p. Would like to know if the gym_gazebo in open_ai_gym_construct is actually complete package? Should I use the original gym_gazebo instead? Here is the link: https://github.com/erlerobot/gym-gazebo

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2019-06-11**:
hello @danny p , I did all the installation you mentioned in your question. However I am receiving the error message below

resource not found: create_description
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/user/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share None

do you know why that is?

**Comment by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on 2020-02-14**:
I'm also trying to using `openai_ros` and `gym`. And I wonder whether you did it in python3 env. Would it be ok if I launch it without python3 env?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no issues here, all the requested nodes with their parameters are correctly launched (and it's normal that the `spawn_turtlebot_model` process end once launched in case you were wondering).

"Nothing happen" because you don't launch the Gazebo GUI (ie. `gzclient`), in your nodes you simply have `gzserver`.
Look at your `main.launch` :

```
  <arg name="paused" value="true"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="false"/>
  <arg name="headless" value="true"/>
  <arg name="stacks"    value="$(optenv TURTLEBOT_STACKS hexagons)"/>  <!-- circles, hexagons --> 
  <arg name="3d_sensor" value="$(optenv TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR kinect)"/>  <!-- kinect, asus_xtion_pro --> 

  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find gym_construct)/worlds/maze_loop_brick.world"/>
  </include>
```

If you change  `<arg name="gui" default="false"/>` to  `<arg name="gui" default="true"/>` everything should be fine.

Or if you don't want to modify the launch file, you can also run :

`roslaunch gym_construct main.launch gui:=true`

In addition : you have `<arg name="paused" value="true"/>`, eventhough you don't use the arg its default value is `false` (if you have to use it and it's set to `true` Gazebo will be started on a paused state)

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danny p](https://answers.ros.org/users/37750/danny-p/) on 2018-09-26**:
I appreciate your comment. I got solved that problem right away, after revising some parts of 'start_qlearnig.py' file which were changed for my_turtlebot2_maze example. Do you know if any different learning codes which can be used instantly in this openai_ros pkgs exists, instead of q-learning?

**Comment by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) on 2018-10-16**:
The learning algorithm used in the examples of openai_ros tutorials is a very simple Q-learning implementation (only provided as an example). Today we have a free [ROS Developers Live Class](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtPPEi5oUa4) where we teach how to change the algorithms in a very simple way

**Comment by [Haresh Miriyala](https://answers.ros.org/users/39616/haresh-miriyala/) on 2019-04-01**:
That worked for me. Thanks. Also, if someone is here for the error message "package [hokuyo] does not have a path", make sure you git checkout to branch 'kinetic' inside the turtlebot folder !